# mysql php - data not entering fully into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am currently building a website that has a gallery which is accessed through php and mysql. When you view on the website the gallery takes the code from mysql and the image from my folder (on the machine).

I am having a problem that when I upload an image (using the php) the image_pathname comes up, so does the image_description (with the image_gallery database), but the author does not - and instead a number appears.

I think it's something maybe I can fix easily but I've been working on the site for a while and my brain is fried - and assuming it's something impossible.

This is my table syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE images(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
image_pathname VARCHAR( 50 ) ,
image_author VARCHAR( 50 ) ,
image_description VARCHAR( 50 ) ,
genreID VARCHAR( 100 )
)
```

This is my HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="upload_file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <p>
              Image Author:
            </p>
            <input type="text" name="image_author"/>

            <p>
              Please enter a decscription:
            </p>
            <input type="text" name="image_description"/>
            <p>
             Please upload an image.
            </p>
            <p>
              Photo:
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
            <input type="file" name="photo"> 


            <input TYPE="submit" name="upload" title="Add image/data to the Database" value="Add Image"/>
          </form>
```

and this is my php:

```
<?php

//This is the directory where images will be saved
$target = "images/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

//This gets all the other information from the form
$name= (isset($_POST['image_author']));
$description= ($_POST['image_description']);
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);


// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db("image_gallery") or die(mysql_error()) ;

//Writes the information to the database
mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (image_author, image_description, image_pathname)
VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$pic')") ;

//Writes the photo to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

//Tells you if its all ok
echo "The file has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory <p> <a href='upload.php'> Go back</a>";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Comment: **Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).** They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). **Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** instead, and **use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).** **[DANGER! You need to prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**

Comment: You can also use `mysqli` functions, which will be easier to integrate into your code.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, would this be okay to use, or could this also be deprecated?

Comment: @Coli-Eza Yes it's ok to use. Prepared statements and `mysqli` are equivalent in security.

Comment: whether you use PDO or mysqli, prepared statements should be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

You are erroneously calling `isset()` when assigning your value to your variable. The result is you get a boolean value, which is what `isset()` retuens) instead of the actual value of `$_POST['image_author']`.

```
 $name= (isset($_POST['image_author']));
```

should be

```
$name= $_POST['image_author'];
```

FYI, you are wide open to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174) and using an [obsolete API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign your form variables like this way and see comment of **Jay Blanchard** about MYSQL API, use instead [MYSQLI](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) which will help you to write SQL INJECTION free code.

```
//This gets all the other information from the form
$name= (isset($_POST['image_author']))? $_POST['image_author']:'';
$description= (isset($_POST['image_description']))? $_POST['image_description']:'';
```